# RegEx to delete alphanumeric and special characters inside a parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to delete all the conditions that match this pattern, parenthesis included

```
(value: "hyhyyt")
```

The string inside could be a number, special characters and so on.

I'm new with regex and I have come up with this expression, but it's not working. Thanks in advance to everyone.

```
 let regex = /^(value:[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&()\\-`.+,/\"])$/g;
 err.message = err.message.replace(regex, '').trim();
```

Comment: `regex = /\(value:[^)]*\)/g`

Comment: wtf, it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: `special characters like /(` specail in way regex, yes ?

Comment: thangs not so eesy as `\(.*?\)` yes ?

Comment: I was referring to special characters in general, I just put those two as an example. I changed the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\(value: .*\)
```

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/WEIVb5/3)

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: The regexp fails as soon as one puts just a single closing parenthesis  in between the quotes which, as the OP explicitly states, is very likely going to happen ... thus it fails already for e.g. `'(value: "hyh)yyt")'`

Comment: @PeterSeliger nice catch. I had made it non greedy, should work now with the greedy quantifier

Comment: ... now the regexp matches an example string like this ... `'(value: "hyhy)(yt") dknk (value: "")'` in its entirety ... but since the OP's question was not specific enough one still does not know for sure how to handle such case. My best bet was that the OP prefers a result like that ... `'dknk'` instead of `''`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger yes, my answer assumes greedy matches is fine. He commented on my answer, so I assume it is correct, no need for complex regexes (so far)

Answer (score 1):

*... edited and improved according to Edward's comment ...*

The regx of the following approach tries to be both flexible/generic and precise enough.

It will, within a given string, recognize multiple (sub) patterns of `'( value: " ... " )'` and/or of `"(value: ' ... ')"`. Thus its limitation, if at all, is a rare edge case of either a `")` sequence enclosed by double quotes or a `')` sequence enclosed by single quotes.

[The regx ... `/\(\s*value\s*:\s*(['"]).*?\1\s*\)/g` ... itself works like that ...](https://regex101.com/r/7xEb1E/5)

- `\(\s*value\s*:\s*` ... match a single `(` followed by an optional (sequence of) whitespace(s) followed by `value` followed by an optional (sequence of) whitespace(s) followed by `:` and again followed by yet another optional (sequence of) whitespace(s),
- `(['"])` ... capture a single occurrence of either a single or a double quote,
- `.*?` ... optionally match any character (sequence) in a non greedy way until the next following pattern gets matched (and which reads) ...
- ... `\1\s*\)` ... match the captured quote type followed by an optional (sequence of) whitespace(s) followed by a single `)`.
- The regx features the global flag in order to match the pattern more than just once.

```js
function stripParenthesizedValues(str) {
  return str.replace((/\(\s*value\s*:\s*(['"]).*?\1\s*\)/g), '').trim();
}

console.log(
  'stripParenthesizedValues(\' foo ((value : "hy\')t")\')  =>',
  `'${ stripParenthesizedValues(' foo (value : "hy\')t")') }'`
);
console.log(
  "stripParenthesizedValues(\"( value : 'hy\")t'  ) bar \")  =>",
  `'${ stripParenthesizedValues("( value : 'hy\")t'  ) bar ") }'`
);

console.log(
  `stripParenthesizedValues("( value : 'hy\")t ' ) foo ( value : 'hy\")t ' ) bar")  =>`,
  `'${ stripParenthesizedValues("( value : 'hy\")t ' ) foo ( value : 'hy\")t ' ) bar") }'`
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: fyi note - Engines do not recognize backreferencess inside of character classes, like `[^\1]`. Since that the case, it sees it as octal `\1` or `\01` or `\001`. See this example 
[\\((ab)\[^\1\]+\1\\)](https://regex101.com/r/sufJlG/1) (abyyab)`(abxyyab)`

Comment: Thanks @Edward for noticing it. I changed and improved the regex accordingly.